# Retrofit - Different API responses on different devices

Tags: java, php, android, retrofit, postman

The problem exactly like the following
I have one api which can provide some data and one apk,

I got my api response with my device and another different old response on the emulator with the same apk!

The emulator response is up to date with the latest changes while the other different response is before the changes.

The app uses retrofit without caching.
So what could be the problem?

Request contains only one header (access token)
Response contains headers like (ETag, Access-Control-Max-Age) but retrofit should not deal with them as there is no cache at all.

Screen shot from postman : [image]

Also when waiting for a while all devices become up to date!

Comment: You should check your HTTP request content between two clients, mainly check the HTTP header.

Comment: As told by sakiM, share your request and headers.

Comment: @sakiM there is only one header (access token) for the sent request, and the response contains headers like (ETag, Access-Control-Max-Age) but the app should not deal with them as there is no cache at all, so where is the problem?

Comment: @azizbekian please check the added headers

Comment: Please verify you receive an expected response using for example [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

Comment: @azizbekian postman request & response headers screenshot added

Comment: @Hoby Can you please expand on what you mean by `when waiting for a while all devices become up to date`? A random thought here. Do you have a load-balancer on the server side where you are running your API? Usually when I come across such an issue, there is a bad / stale server left behind the load balancer, which is still serving old responses. Load balancers usually use round-robin method to assign a server instance to the requests, and if they use sticky sessions, your scenario of different devices getting different response is definitely possible.

Comment: Proxying your traffic could help you find the answer: http://www.versionestabile.it/blog/ios-simulator-and-android-emulator-http-proxy/

Comment: *The app uses retrofit without caching* - can you show how you disabled caching on Retrofit?

Comment: @shadowsheep thanks I'll try that method

Comment: @riyaz-ali there is no cache object for retrofit : new OkHttpClient.Builder().cache(null).build();

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure with this?

> The app uses retrofit without caching

Based on this https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/678, I think that retrofit (OkHttp inside retrofit) caching your query.

You can change this behavior by 2 ways:

- add ?_t=TIMESTAMP into your app query url
- remove 'Access-Control-Max-Age' header from your server response

Comment: thanks for your help, but adding ?_t=TIMESTAMP didnt work, I'll try the second option and get back

Answer (score 1):

Or you can create new OkHttp client to retrofit and write something like that:

```
new OkHttpClient.Builder().cache(null).build();
```

or

```
Request.cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I already using the first solution with null cache object and the second solution gave me the same result

Comment: Cool, I am glad to hear that I can help you)

Answer (score 0):

> So what could be the problem?

If you dont' find the problem on the client, you should look for it on the server side. Any kind of caching (on the database, or on the HTTP response level) can show this behavior.

Without further knowledge about your setup and your test environment it is impossible to figure out what the problem could be. You write

> Also when waiting for a while all devices become up to date

What does that mean? How do you determine, if your devices are up to date?

In your complicated case, with backend involved, you should provide an example project on Github where this behavior can be reproduced.